# How to return true if a number is between 2 numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What's the most efficient way to return true in a `if()` condition to check if a number is in between 2 other. My biggest problem is that the higher number and the lower number has to be exchangable(see examples). It also has to exclude the comparator (as in within more than in between?).

Examples

x=14, y=7 and we check if b=8 is between x and y: `return true`

x=6, y=12 and we check if b=11 is between x and y: `return true`

x=6, y=12 and we check if b=12 is between x and y: `return false`

x=12, y=6 and we check if b=12 is between x and y: `return false`

x=6, y=12 and we check if b=6 is between x and y: `return false`

Comment: `(b < x && b > y) ? true : false`

Comment: @Kinduser - There is no reason for the `? true : false` bit. Just `(b < x && b > y)` has the same effect.

Comment: These won't work with the second example where x can be the smaller number as well!

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Right (:

Comment: x > y ? (b < x && b > y) : (b > x && b < y)

Comment: Can this go directly in like this `if(x > y ? (b < x && b > y) : (b > x && b < y)` ) ?

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier i believe so? why not try? :) or you can try JLRishe s method and call if(inbetween(x, y, b)) or you can extract what i suggested you into a method

Comment: Works perfectly! https://jsfiddle.net/scharpentier0/sj0kegva/ If you don't mind making an answer, I'll make it the selected answer.

Comment: @let_the_coding_begin if you didn't see, OP would like your comment as an answer — `function between(x, y, b) { return x > y ? (b < x && b > y) : etc.` (personally, I would use _n_ in place of _b_)

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier  will do thank you for notifying Stephen

Comment: `Number.prototype.isBetween = function(x, y) { return x > y ? (this < x && this > y) : (this > x && this < y); };` => `var n = 6; n.isBetween(12, 6);` produces `false` (not answering with this because mucking with the JS object prototypes is considered bad form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
x > y ? (b < x && b > y) : (b > x && b < y)
```

to get the result you want. To use it in an if statement you can either use the equation directly or extract it into a method and substitute it into the if statement.

Here is also the link you provided so other people can see it all together :)

https://jsfiddle.net/scharpentier0/sj0kegva/

Comment: Anything of the form `if (condition) { console.log("true"); } else { console.log("false"); }` can be reduced to `console.log( condition );` More generally, anything in the form `if (condition) return true else return false` can be reduced to `return condition` which is how I formulated it in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```js
function isBetween(x, y, b) {
    return b > Math.min(x, y) && b < Math.max(x, y);
}

console.log(isBetween(14, 7, 8));
console.log(isBetween(6, 12, 11));
console.log(isBetween(6, 12, 12));
console.log(isBetween(12, 6, 12));
console.log(isBetween(6, 12, 6));
```

Comment: I was about to post the same :D

Comment: I would argue this is "wrong" given the requirements. Yes it works, but he says, "What's the most efficient way" I cannot imagine that having to call `Math.min` and `Math.max` is more efficient than just a simple if statement.

Comment: @dman2306 Fair point, though it's efficient in terms of code length and readability. If OP wants the _most_ efficient way to do something (in terms of execution time), then that's a very subjective question (and smells of micro-optimizations).

Comment: @JLRishe Actually I couldn't disagree more. Readability is subjective. Execution time is not. It is either faster or it isn't. If you mean it depends on JS engine, sure, but that's not subjective, it just means that you need to look at multiple browsers to be sure. While it might be a "micro optimization" and you might think it unimportant, it doesn't mean that your answer meets his needs. Perhaps this micro-optimization is because he is executing it billions of times a day...

Comment: @dman2306 How can you declare anything the _most_ efficient way to do anything that's not completely trivial? (Especially with the differences between JS engines).

Comment: @JLRishe a CPU has a finite set of instructions. There must exist some set of instructions that produces the optimal results given a particular task. Sure, there may be more than one optimal set, but there must be at least 1 optimal set. I can guarantee you this, creating stack frames to call methods is NOT the optimal way. There is a reason why in languages such as C/C++ min/max functions are often optimized as inline if statements during compilation.

Comment: @dman2306 Any decent JavaScript engine will inline `Math.min` and `Math.max` for you. I would not concern myself over such petty micro-optimizations and I certainly would not trash this [rather well-thought-out] answer over such a trivial matter.

Answer (score 2):

the order does not matter if you evaluate them both

```
   function between(x, value1, value2) {
  return (x > value1 && x < value2) || (x < value1 && x > value2);
  }
  // ...
 if (between(x, 14, 7)) {
  // something
  }
```

**EDIT:**
remember to use the (=> <=) OR (< >) accordingly to your needs either if you want to make a include between or an exclude between.

example:

```
   function between(x, value1, value2) {
  return (x >= value1 && x <= value2) || (x <= value1 && x >= value2);
  }
```

will return TRUE for  `between(7, 14, 7) or between(14, 14, 7)`

while

```
   function between(x, value1, value2) {
  return (x > value1 && x < value2) || (x < value1 && x > value2);
  }
```

will return FALSE for  `between(7, 14, 7) or between(14, 14, 7)`

Comment: OP says _"It also has to exclude the comparator"_ so your `<=` and `>=` should be `<` and `>` to exclude the limits.

Comment: The question **does** state (as I quoted) _"It also has to exclude the comparator"_ and an example `x=12, y=6 and we check if b=12 is between x and y: return false` demonstrates it.  Your `between(12, 12, 6)` gets that answer wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take the functional programming approach:

```js
const compileIsBetween = function (x, y) {
  const min = Math.min(x, y);
  const max = Math.max(x, y);
  return function (num) {
    return num > min && num < max;
  }
}

console.log(compileIsBetween(14, 7)(8));
console.log(compileIsBetween(6, 12)(11));
console.log(compileIsBetween(6, 12)(12));
console.log(compileIsBetween(12, 6)(12));
console.log(compileIsBetween(6, 12)(6));

const isBetween10and20 = compileIsBetween(10, 20);
console.log(isBetween10and20(12))
console.log(isBetween10and20(23))
console.log(isBetween10and20(2))
```